# how to get size or count the number of properties of an object?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there any method to count number of properties (or size) of an object (don't want to use any loop) ?

Suppose i have an object obj as,

```
obj={id:'0A12',name:'nishant',phone:'mobile'};
```

Then is there any method which results 3 in this case ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/5uFgu/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`Object.keys`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.2.3.14)  returns an array containing the names of the object's *own enumerable properties*, so:

```
var count = Object.keys(obj).length;
```

Note that there may well be a loop involved (within `Object.keys`), but at least it's within the JavaScript engine. `Object.keys` was added by ES5, so older browsers may not have it (it can be "shimmed," though; search for "es5 shim" for options).

Note that that's not quite the same list of properties that `for-in` iterates, as `for-in` includes properties inherited from the prototype.

I don't believe there's any way to get a list of the object's non-enumerable properties (that would be the point of them!).

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) in [modern browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys#Compatibility)

```
Object.keys(obj).length
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use

```
Object.keys(obj).length;
```

P.S. Only in modern browsers.

Comment: just asking..how is this different from @Arun P Johny answer..

Comment: Might have been posted before seeing that answer. Shows only 3 min difference between the posts.